# Как заменить ветку master другой веткой?

Tags: git, git-branch

Ситуация такая: была ветка `master`. В какой-то момент от нее отделилась ветка `new_feature`. Потом основная разработка велась в этой новой ветке, а в ветке `master` проводился только багфикс и добавление маленьких фич. В конечном итоге, в ветке `new_feature` проект был по сути переписан, многие файлы удалены, сильно поменялась структура и т.п.

Вопрос: можно ли теперь как-то ветку `master` сделать веткой, например, `old_version`, а ветку `new_feature` сделать `master-ом`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Если смержить **точно не получается,** то подменить ветки можно следующим образом:

  ```
  git checkout new_feature
  git merge -s ours master
  git checkout master
  git merge new_feature
  ```
- Естественно, что такой реплейс веток приведет к проблемам при `pull` у всех девелоперов, которые продолжали работать над `master`, поэтому стоит сообщить им о том, что все было переписано и попросить сделать `reset --hard`.

Answer (score 5):

Попросту переименуйте ветки.

```
git branch -m master old_version
git branch -m new_feature master
```

Comment: Или создать новый проект, взяв за основу один из релизов new_feature.

Comment: В таком случае не сработает `fast-forward` для `git push`, что обычно не очень хорошо.